# Automatic outlook emails using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have this code I found somewhere over the internet attached to the end of my code. It copies the needed sheet, attaches it to an email and then sends it.

```
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

ActiveSheet.Copy
Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

With Destwb
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    End If
End With

TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "Payments due in " & Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Now), "mmm-yyyy")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With Destwb
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "Fadel@wataniya.ps"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Payments due in " & Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Now), "mmm-yyyy")
        .Body = "FYI"
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With
Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

When I try to run the code again (in the same session) without restarting Outlook the following error pops up:

```
runtime error, 
automation error, 
system call failed,
```

and the debugger highlights this line of the code

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

and it says something about a blocked object.

How can I repeat this multiple times without restarting outlook ?

Comment: Before you `Set OutApp = Nothing`, try doing `OutApp.Quit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following and am able to send multiple emails without issue

```
sub sendEmail(varSubject, varBody, varTo, varCC)

Dim objOL 
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
If objOL Is Nothing Then
        Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        objOL.Session.Logon "Outlook", , False, True
    End If
Dim objMsg 
Set objMsg = objOL.CreateItem(0) 
With objMSG 
    .Subject = varSubject & " Updated - " &Date
    .To = varTo
    .cc = varCC
    .Body = varBody
    .Send
End With

end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A few problems:

1. Your first with statement `With Destwb` did contain any submethods, so it doesn't need to be used.
2. `On Error GoTo 0` - This error handling is Obsolete. Read ["To Err is Vbscript"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692852.aspx)
3. Please don't put yours or someone elses email in your code...lol I think i sent an accidental email after I repaired your code.

Anyways, here it is....

```
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim FileFormatNum As Long
Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
Dim Destwb As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

ActiveSheet.Copy
Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
    FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
Else
    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
End If

TempFilePath = Environ("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "Payments due in " & Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Now), "mmm-yyyy")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With Destwb
    On Error Resume Next
    .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "FileName Taken!"
    With OutMail
        .To = "Fadel@wataniya.ps"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Payments due in " & Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Now), "mmm-yyyy")
        .Body = "FYI"
        .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
        .Send
    End With
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With
OutMail.Quit
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks man, but still not working when running again without restarting the outlook.

Comment: Well, are you changing the filenames for each load? because it needs a unique file name everytime. I just tried that same code and received 2 emails from myself right in a row.

Comment: Just FYI `Environ$("temp")` is perfectly acceptable. Try it :)

Comment: oh cool! New Toys! :D My bad Fadel & David. Will update my answer.

Comment: can i add a couple of lines to the code which opens the outlook when the code starts running and then closes it or restart it or refresh it or whatever?